# Need help sorting

Tags: batch-file

Ok, I get a report every day, a passenger manifest. It is just given in the order that they take the reservation, not the actual time for the passenger pick up. Each order contains 4 lines. Line 1, customer number, Line 2, customer name, Line 3, Pick Up time (24 hour clock), and Line 4 Pick Up address.

I use Wordpad or I can also use MS Word 2010. I need to sort this list by their Pick up time (24 hour clock)
with the earliest pick up first. The very first thing on the 3rd line is the time (ex: 04:15). Is there an easier way to sort this without having to manually eye this manifest and copy and pasting them in order?

Comment: What kind of file is it? .txt?

Comment: could you post also the content of example file?And especially the full format of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Consider in your manifest are 4 lines per passenger and line #3 is the sorting criterion this should work:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "plist=passenger.lst"
set "slist=pass_sort.lst"
set /a counter=10000

for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("%plist%") do (
    set "line=%%i"
    set /a index=counter%%4
    set /a pasno=counter/4
    set "$a!pasno!!index!=!line!"
    if !index! equ 2 set "$b!line!!counter!=!pasno!"
    set /a counter+=1
)
(for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%i in ('set "$b"') do (
 for /l %%a in (0,1,3) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%x in ("!$a%%i%%a!") do echo(%%x
)))>"%slist%"
type "%slist%"
```

The code doesn't work with `=!^` in the text. This might be fixed if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%b in (number name pickTime) do set %%b=
for /F "delims=" %%a in (original.txt) do (
   if not defined number   (set "number=%%a")   else (
   if not defined name     (set "name=%%a")     else (
   if not defined pickTime (set "pickTime=%%a") else (
   set "order[!pickTime!]!number!=!name!=%%a"
   for %%b in (number name pickTime) do set %%b=
   )))
)   
(for /F "tokens=2-5 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set order[') do (
   echo %%b
   echo %%c
   echo %%a
   echo %%d
)) > sorted.txt
type sorted.txt
```

This program fail if the input file have `[]=!` characters. This may be fixed, if needed.

Comment: If I understand this correctly `SET` is doing the ordering? Is this documented anywhere? It certainly isn't in `SET /?`

Answer (score 0):

Below are links to example, with personal info changed and redacted.
On the third line is the Time for PU  (pickup)  this is the only time I need to go by.  but as you will see by their trip number there is a -A  and a -B for each name.  A trip is going and B trip is returning.  the time returning does not matter, only the time going.  but each trip A and B needs to be together in order from the earliest PU time to the latest PU time.

I will post below what the output needs to look like when I manually sort them:

I do this in Wordpad and saved as a *rtf

So only the PU time in -A is relevant, but the corresponding -b record needs to accompany it.

Here is the link to the List Example:   http://www.docstoc.com/docs/157731527/TRIP-SHEET

Here is a link to how the output should look: http://www.docstoc.com/docs/157731398/OUTPUT

Pay no attention to the 3 dashes below each line, the margins were not wide enough, that is suppose to be all one continuous dotted line.